# How to schedule a python job in Asia/Kolkata timezone

Tags: python, timezone, schedule, pytz

Hi I have successfully scheduled a python job by using the below mentioned code

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I am doing this job!")


schedule.every().monday.at("14:00").do(job)
schedule.every().tuesday.at("14:00").do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("14:00").do(job)
schedule.every().thursday.at("14:00").do(job)
schedule.every().friday.at("14:00").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Now I need to implement the schedule only in Asia/Kolkata time zone. Can we use pytz library with this?

Comment: Yes and no. In the absence of any additional configuration, the jobs will run in whichever time zone the operating system is configured to use.

Comment: How can I make it independent from the server? By hard coding the timezone in the python script itself?

Comment: You would have to _know_ the time zone of the server. A common convention is to always run servers in UTC, and then the rest will be easy; but without knowledge of how the server is configured, all we can really tell you is that the problem statement needs more details.

Comment: Maybe this is a solution for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47356453/python-schedule-jobs-with-different-timezones

The [scheduler](https://github.com/DigonIO/scheduler) library for python offers support for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must use schedule library and you want to work with different timezones, then you'll have to manually specify the time according to the time zone to schedule library.

```
    import schedule
    import time
    from datetime import datetime
    import pytz # you'll have to install pytz to get timezones

    def job():
        print("I am doing this job!")

    # Create a time zone object for Asia/Kolkata
    kolkata_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')

    # Define the desired time for the job in Kolkata time
    job_time = datetime.now(kolkata_tz).replace(hour=14, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

    # Schedule the job for each weekday at the specified time 
    schedule.every().monday.at(job_time.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)

   schedule.every().tuesday.at(job_time.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)

   schedule.every().wednesday.at(job_time.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)

   schedule.every().thursday.at(job_time.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)

   schedule.every().friday.at(job_time.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```